# Storybook Angular NX workspace: How to publish using Chromatic?

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook, chromatic

Hi Does anyone know how to Run Storybook Chromatic in an NX workspace ?
My Angular app and libs are working fine when Serving locally, I have run Stories for my projects fine.  I have even built and published the stories locally.
What I want is to publish it to remote using Chromatic but I do not know how.

Is there a process for this? I have not found one yet.
I am trying something really messy at the moment - but it is not working.
This is my failed attempt:

Adding a run script to the Workspace package.json:

```
"build-storybook": "./node_modules/@storybook/angular/bin/index.js build-storybook --output-dir ./dist/storybook -c ./libs/cwb-panel/.storybook”
```

Gives this error:

```
Command failed with exit code 1: npm run --silent build-storybook -- --output-dir /var/folders/qz/2d3l6_blahblahblah

error: unknown option '--output-dir'
```

I am stumped, there must be a way, just not sure what it is :(

Comment: Hi - I have the same question about how to publish (make a deployable artifact) when using Storybook into nwrl/nx workspace. Have you figured out maybe?

Comment: Not yet, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

On your nx project you should have a `workspace.json` (or `project.json` in 13.x) that has some storybook config already:

```
"storybook": {
  "executor": "@nrwl/storybook:storybook",
  "options": {
    "uiFramework": "@storybook/react",
    "port": 4400,
    "config": { "configFolder": "libs/ui-library/.storybook" }
  },
  "configurations": { "ci": { "quiet": true } }
},
"build-storybook": {
  "executor": "@nrwl/storybook:build",
  "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
  "options": {
    "uiFramework": "@storybook/react",
    "outputPath": "dist/storybook/ui-library",
    "config": { "configFolder": "libs/ui-library/.storybook" }
  },
  "configurations": { "ci": { "quiet": true } }
}
```

You can build a nx storybook publishable version by running: `npx nx serve ui-library:build-storybook`

This will generate the folder `dist/storybook/ui-library` that is the one you want to use either in Chromatic or deploying it elsewhere.

References:

- https://nx.dev/storybook/overview-angular

Answer (score 2):

@feralamillo is right, but his answer is incomplete.

You can't just run the build-storybook command, you need to customize the command like this:

```
npx chromatic --project-token=cXXXXX -d=dist/storybook/component-name
```

I will give you a step by step:

1. Build your storybook (`npx nx run logo:build-storybook`)
2. Create your project in the Chromatic Platform and get the project key
3. Use the custom command to use your dist directory (`npx chromatic --project-token=cXXXXX -d=dist/storybook/component-name`) More Information: https://www.chromatic.com/docs/cli
4. (Optional) Create a custom command in your **project.json** to execute this. More information:https://nx.dev/l/a/executors/run-commands-builder
5. I don't know how to manage chromatic in a monorepo, but here I found some ways to manage it: https://www.chromatic.com/docs/monorepos.html#monorepos